# How to create a forest game scene in unity3d?

Tags: unity, scene-graph

I am pretty new to game development. I have started using unity3d.

I have created simple games for which I have used plane (3d gameObject). Now, I want to move a step forward I want to create a forest with mountain and trees. So, I went through few tutorials and concluded terrain (3d Object) will be best fit.

**Issue**: My player falls down from the terrain due to gravity and if i disable gravity then my player flies up in y axes when moved over mountains. What is the way i can create terrain with gravity and so that my player doesn't fall from the terrain.

Can anyone throw light on how do overcome above mentioned issue.

Comment: Did u apply Mesh Collider on  Terrain...?

Comment: yes, Box collider is applied on the terrain by default.

Comment: does your player have a collider and rigid body on it as well...?

Comment: Yes, I have made player a rigidBody.

Comment: And what about any collider?

Comment: Your Gameobject needs a collider and rigidbody. Make sure your collider is not trigger collider.

Comment: My GameObject is rigidbody and has a collider. I am not sure about trigger collider. I don't have access to the scene i tried. I will have access to after 3-4 hrs. Once i have access i make sure trigger collider is not checked and then update comment here. Thank you for the support. :)

Comment: No prob dude...! Pleasure been all mine... :)

Comment: @ShraddhaPatel : Thank a lot. Mesh Collider was not there on Terrain. Not it is working as expected. :) Thank you again and I understood I need to read a lot more before trying out a 3d game ;)

Comment: Hmm u sorted it out glad to know that I could help u... ;)